# SublimeREPL for IPython under Windows not possible. Any workaround?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, ipython, sublimerepl

SublimeREPL says 'IPython doesn't work under SublimeREPL on Windows' when I select Ipython from it.

Is there any solution out there for this great plugin to work with IPython on Windows as well.

Comment: The [`FAQ`](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#faq) has a single question, which explains that with `SublimeREPL`, "anything *terminal like (mc, ipython, vim) will not work! SublimeREPL has a sister project: SublimePTY that aims to bring real terminal emulator to SublimeText2." So, did you look at that?

Comment: SublimeREPL (with IPython) works perfectly fine in ST2 on Windows. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Are you serious? Look what it gives me: http://snag.gy/dlxgQ.jpg (the above msgbox text is misleading, I didn't try to initialize it by typing ipython on the python interpreter but from TOOLS menu)

Comment: @Honesta: What version of Sublime Text and SublimeREPL do you have? As I said in my answer, "it seems like you just need a newer version." Have you tried updating?

Comment: Sublime 2.0.1 SublimeREPL just installed it from Control Package. It must be the latest. (Windows 7)

Comment: @abarnert what are your versions?

Comment: @Honesta see my reply below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't made any changes to config files within the `Packages/SublimeREPL` directory, try erasing/backing it up, and running the following in the `Packages` directory:

```
git clone git://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL.git
```

to get the absolute latest version. Assuming you have IPython set up properly on your system, you ***should*** be able to choose `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python - IPython` and have it run fine. Make sure you have the [latest build](http://www.sublimetext.com/dev) of Sublime Text 2. I have it set up at work on WinXP with ST2 Build 2220, IPython 0.13.2, and the latest versions of NumPy and matplotlib/pylab, and it works like a charm.

If this still doesn't work, let me know and I'll try and walk you through it...

Comment: I have never used git. should I install it for CMD?

Comment: Yes I did install it using git. It runs but gives the following error:

Comment: ipy_repl.py"
    from IPython.frontend.terminal.console.app import ZMQTerminalIPythonApp

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\console\app.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.zmq.ipkernel import IPKernelApp

  File "IPython\zmq\__init__.py", line 67
    check_for_zmq('2.1.4')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\zmq\__init__.py", line 53, in check_for_zmq

    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(module, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.zmq requires pyzmq >= 2.1.4

Comment: I updated pyzmq and It works. Thanks. Though the tab doesn't work like it does when I run Ipython on CMD (after the module name and dhe dot(.) it is supposed to give the functins, but it doesnt. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: try master branch from github. If something doesn't work, get in touch with me (github issues), I'll try to help:)

Hi everyone,

there is no need for such heated discussion :) SublimeREPL is in a bit of a transitional state right now. Development is progressing steadily (https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/commits/master) with most of my personal focus on Python/IPython.

However there was no release to Package Control for some time now, since I switched to Sublime Text 3 and Linux in march. This is mostly because ST2 (python2) -> St3 (python3) port dropped some functions, and compatibility with OSX & Windows isn't 'production ready' yet. I'm afraid to release current code to everyone, as it'll most definitely not work for some people.

To cut the long story short. SublimeREPL version available in Package Control is stable but out of date. SublimeREPL from git master is used daily by me and several other people, but I test it only on Linux.

Will Bond is planning to roll out new version of Package Control soon (https://twitter.com/wbond/status/334753348018388992). It will allow me to target specific versions of SublieText with different code, and roll out new code separately for compatible platforms.

On a related note: SublimePTY was not updated for a very long time and its future is uncertain at best.

Comment: Thanks about this Plugin, You've done a great job. I got a question:  At Ipython when I type modulename.(dot) TAB it shows the list of implemented functions while SublimeREPL IPython doesn't do that. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

When I did a search, the first Google result took me to the Sublime Forums, where [this thread](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2964&p=46028&hilit=REPL#p46028) says "IPython is working on Windows for some time now".

So, It seems like you just need a newer version of Sublime Text and/or SublimeREPL.

Alternatively, as [the SublimeREPL FAQ](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL#faq) says:

> 1. Is this a terminal emulator?
>
> No. Shell (cmd.exe/bash) REPL can be used for simple tasks (file creation, git init etc.) but anything terminal like (mc, ipython, vim) will not work! SublimeREPL has a sister project: [SublimePTY](https://github.com/wuub/SublimePTY) that aims to bring real terminal emulator to SublimeText2.

That seems a little out of date, but you can try `SublimePTY` anyway.

Finally, it looks like the author of SublimeREPL follows the [Sublime Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) pretty closely, and in fact a large chunk of the forum seems to be devoted to plugins. So, you will probably do better asking there, rather than here.

Comment: @MattDMo: What are you replying to? My quote from SublimeREPL's author saying that "IPython is working on Windows for some time now"? My statement that the official FAQ (which implies the opposite) "seems a little out of date"? Either way, it sounds like you're arguing for the same point I already made, not against it.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear, it was the statement from the FAQ about ipython (as a terminal program) not working in SublimeREPL. From what wuub has told me he hasn't really worked on SublimePTY in a while, and it's pretty rough to use, so I wouldn't recommend it...

Comment: @MattDMo: Yes, I already said the FAQ "seems a little out of date" in the answer.